# what is good (stackexchange) form for questions?

Tags: community

I wind up on these pages a lot when searching from google and the like. I see a lot of questions closed as off-topic. That doesn't feel very welcoming for this uninitiated pseudo-nerd. I'm pretty sure this is a friendly community. Can you point me to why so many search results seem like they are flamed closed?

Comment: Hello and welcome! Not to intentionally be unwelcoming, but this is more of a meta question rather than hardware/software related: https://meta.superuser.com/

Comment: Questions being closed are an opportunity for the author to improve a question that otherwise would be deleted.  A question being closed, shouldn’t be taken personally, as the action is against the question not the author.

Answer (score 1):

The reason these sites are helpful is that they are kept on-topic by trusted community members. More often than not, off-topic questions aren't ignored... they are [migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) to another forum of the Stack Exchange where they can be better answered by people more familiar with that topic. A topic that is closed as off-topic probably isnt suited for any question-answer site. This is a question-answer site... It is not a do-my-homework-site, nor a help-me-I-have-no-clue site. We are not here to provide you with generalized information (i.e. Where can I learn more about foo?), when a  quick google search can give you that.

Not all of these types of questions are bad... they just don't belong here. You don't expect Netflix to send you sandwiches. Sandwiches aren't bad, they just aren't in Netflix's scope.

Hope this helps... FYI this question is  super off topic, and will most likely get migrated to [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)... Not because its a bad question or we are unfriendly, just 'cause it doesn't belong here.